# Getting null reference error in linq expression when trying to join more than 2 tables using defaultifempty method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to left join three tables using defaultIfEmpty to assign null value if there is no match in the second table and then i am using the second table values to join the third table.

```
var test = (from Eqpt in Eqpts
            join SystemEqpt in FleetSysEqpt on SystemEqpt.ID equals eqpt.SwCompanyEqptKey into sysEqptTemp
            from a in sysEqptTemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join System in System on a.SwFleetSystemKey equals System.ID 
)
```

I am getting null object reference error when 'a' becomes null. Any Suggestions to check whether 'a' is null while joining.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add a `where` condition

```
var test = (from Eqpt in Eqpts
            join SystemEqpt in FleetSysEqpt on SystemEqpt.ID equals eqpt.SwCompanyEqptKey into sysEqptTemp
            from a in sysEqptTemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join System in System on a.SwFleetSystemKey equals System.ID 
            where a != null
)
```

Comment: No I am still getting same exception.

Comment: Add it above the join, not below it.

Comment: Now I am not getting the exception but the result set is wrong. Final result is not including data from first  table(Eqpts) if there is not record in the second table. It looks like an inner join.